# Is there an efficient way to audit the split of Production and Dev Dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm working on a React/Typescript project and have been asked to cleanup the `package.json` because some dependencies are suspected to have been installed as full `dependencies` rather than `devDependencies`.

There are a significant amount of items so I am wondering whether there is a sensible (and ideally semi-automated) methodology for auditing the file in such a way that I can transfer only those dependencies that are required for production to the correct list?

Comment: I would do this by hand. There may be edge-cases that automation will miss, and if this is something that's been given to you by your work, don't half-ass it, commit something that's wrong, and then have to redo the whole project again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In terms of doing by hand, are there any broad-strokes ways to determine if transferring a dependency into dev only is safe? In mind I have: move a single dependency, `npm install` again, run all tests and start the app to ensure it loads properly. Is the the right sort of idea?

Comment: I've changed my mind a little. If you go into your source folder you could `grep` for all the lines in all the files that start with `import` and end with a semi-colon, and that would give you a long list of dependencies. You'll be able spot very quickly which ones are React components/helpers etc from 3rd-party dependencies. [Here's a list from one of my projects](https://pastebin.com/wBSCMu4G). Would that `grep` command help you at all?